# passing value to javascript to php variable: It do not work?

Tags: javascript, php, parameter-passing

In this program `similar_text` function do not work but `echo` successfully print `$var_1` and `$var_2`. What is the exact error?

```
<script>

var j=prompt('1st name','Name')

var l=prompt('2nd name','Name')
</script>

<?php
$var_1 = '<script>document.write(j)</script>'; 
$var_2 = '<script>document.write(l)</script>'; 

similar_text($var_1, $var_2, $percent); 
echo $var_1, $var_2;
echo $percent; 
?>
```

Comment: PHP executes on the server, Javascript executes on the client. You can **NOT** mix the languages like that.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is executed first, on the server, then it gets served and then only javascript is executed on the client-side. so the variables you are using in php part are not set at that moment.

If you need to interact with a php script from javascript, you odd to use an ajax request.

Answer (score 1):

you need close php and open again

```
<script>
var j=prompt('1st name','Name')
var l=prompt('2nd name','Name')
</script>

<?php
$var_1 = '<script>document.write(?>j<?php)</script>'; 
$var_2 = '<script>document.write(?>l<?php)</script>'; 

similar_text($var_1, $var_2, $percent); 
echo $var_1, $var_2;
echo $percent; 

?>
```

or same.